# How can I remove the need for port numbers in URLs in IIS 8.5?

Tags: iis-8

I have inherited an IIS 8.5 server where several websites are present, and they are currently accessed by:

```
http://example.com:8081
http://example.com:8082
http://example.com:8083
```

I would like to be able to access them by:

```
http://example.com/sitename1
http://example.com/sitename2
http://example.com/sitename3
```

How can I make it so? Ideally, I would not have to change all the existing port numbers, since there are active users.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing allows you to manipulate URLs as wished.

Answer (score 0):

Do sitename1, sitename2, and sitename3 correspond to ports 8081, 8082, and 8083 respectively? If yes, you can also try to use url rewrite to redirect the current url to another url. The following rule you can use as a reference:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^sitename1$" />
    <conditions>
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.company.com" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com:8081" />
</rule>
```